# How to get modal information submitted by a user emailed to you

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a modal on Bootstrap with the fields of information that I want to collect. What I would like is for when the 'submit' button is pushed, that information gets emailed to me.  Is there a way to do this simply without turning this into a rails app? At the moment I've only done the index html & css code so far:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialogue">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4>Contact RE Ledger</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group"><!-- For every row -->
              <label for="Contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Name: </label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Please put your full name">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"><!-- For every row -->
              <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Email: </label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="email@siteexample.com">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"><!-- For every row -->
              <label for="contact-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Message: </label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea rows="8" class="form-control"> </textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close it</a>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: To submit the form automatically, back end code such as PHP, asp.net, etc. Is required. You could use the `mailto` protocol to auto populate the users default email app with a new email  (not recommended).

Comment: Some people may say you haven't trying anything yet regarding what you want to accomplish... At least try something and if you get stuck the guys will gladly help you. Don't just post HTML and CSS and ask the community to write your code. Try githut for that ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Google Apps Mail` for achieve your goal. Don't need any Backend server like PHP, Python, Java, Ruby, Node.js etc.

[Check out this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server) for more details.

Comment: Thanks - I attacked this with Google apps Mail. Got as far as points 10 & 11 in your article though but couldn't get the Java 'Ajax' script to function ...

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.  First you use [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) that I find the easiest.  Here is some sample php code for sending an email:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You could use google apps mail, however if you are working with forms and data you will probably have to use some backend language in the future like php, so it is worth [taking a look at now](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php).

Let me know if you have any other questions